When using invoke-command with credentials, credential parameter not properly initialized
So I tried calling the following code with and without credentials.
$username = "user"
$password = "password"
$cred = new-object -argumentlist $username, $password

#Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer -FilePath "C:\Some\Path.ps1" -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -FilePath "C:\Some\Path.ps1"

after calling in cmd appeared the following lines:
cmdlet New-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
TypeName:

Since I do not know what this parameters are referring to I type a letter and then the following error occurs:

new-object : Cannot find type [;]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At C:\Some\Path.ps1:8 char:9
+ $cred = new-object -argumentlist $username, $password
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

[localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken

I have abs no idea what it means. Can somebody help me please?

Look here. I use that approach

new-object  has a mandatory TypeName parameter - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-7.4. Because you  haven't specified a value for this parameter in your new-object -argumentlist $username, $password, PowerSehll is prompting you for a value. The subsequent error is telling you the value you entered isn't a valid type. The next Access Denied error is telling you the credential supplied to Invoke-Command is invalid, which we already know because it's $null due to the previous error

ty so much for these tips. So far I`ve tried this and
$username = "user"
$password = "pass"
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
and with the following 2 errors:
new-object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".
&&&
Invoke-Command : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Credential' because it is null.

Is it enough to only give the computer name and password as credentials or do I need the domain too?

Dumb question the one above sorry. I just started Powershell a week ago.

@AnneMarie Is this for interactive use, or for headless/unattended use?

it is for interactive use. I have to run a script at work from 1 computer to another and I can enter all computers. So far I am trying to run it on localhost and it fails

Don't fret - PowerShell is a strangely complex language runtime, and the initial learning curve can be quite steep :)
In .NET - the runtime framework on top of which PowerShell is built - all objects have a type - and so you need to specify the type of object you want when creating one.
To find the appropriate type name, let's first take a look at the -Credential parameter to which you will be passing the object as an argument. We can use Get-Help <commandName> -Parameter <parameterName> to inspect the parameter definition:
PS ~> Get-Help Invoke-Command -Parameter Credential

-Credential <pscredential>

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    Named
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByPropertyName)
    Parameter set name           ComputerName, Uri, FilePathComputerName, FilePathUri, VMId, VMName, FilePathVMId, FilePathVMName
    Aliases                      None
    Dynamic?                     false


On the first line we see that it expects a value of type pscredential.
For interactive scripts, the easiest way to construct a pscredential object is to use the Get-Credential command - it'll prompt you for a password and return a pscredential object you can then pass to Invoke-Command (and re-use later if desirable):
PS ~> $credential = Get-Credential -Username $username # this will prompt you for a password
Enter your credentials.
Password for user asd: ********

PS ~> Invoke-Command {...} -Credential $credential # now we can pass the credential object to the command parameter

Assuming the target computers are all part of the same domain and the credentials you possess have access to connect to the WinRM endpoint on them, you can reuse the same credential object against them all:
foreach ($computerName in $listOfComputerNames) {
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -ScriptBlock { ... } -Credential $credential
}

... or you can pass all the computer names to Invoke-Command in one go:
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $listOfComputerNames -ScriptBlock { ... } -Credential $credential


For unattended use however, you might still need to find a way to instantiate a credential object without Get-Credential.
Let's try passing the correct type name to New-Object:
PS ~> $cred = New-Object -TypeName pscredential -ArgumentList $username, $password

New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".
At line:1 char:9
+ $cred = New-Object -TypeName pscredential -ArgumentList $username, $p ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Oh no! The arguments passed to New-Object doesn't match the constructor parameters defined by the pscredential type.
The easiest way to inspect all overload signatures for a given type's constructor is to invoke the static new method on the type, without passing an argument list:
PS ~> [pscredential]::new

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
pscredential new(string userName, securestring password)
pscredential new(psobject pso)

The constructor with the signature pscredential new(string userName, securestring password) is probably exactly what we want - but it says it's expecting a securestring-type object rather than a regular string.
To instantiate a [securestring] from plain text, we can use the ConvertTo-SecureString cmdlet:
PS ~> $securePassword = $password |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
PS ~> $credential = New-Object pscredential -ArgumentList $username, $securePassword
PS ~> # yay, no more errors!
Ps ~> Invoke-Command {...} -Credential $credential

As an alternative to the New-Object command, you can also use the static ::new method we used to discover the constructor signatures earlier:
PS ~> $credential = [pscredential]::new($username, $securePassword)


Thank you so much for telling me how to instantiate a secure string. I did not know how to do that. I will re read a couple more times to put everything to practice

The credentials popup no longer appears and I am so so glad about it.

@AnneMarie That's great to hear, you're most welcome! If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left :)

just clicked ;)

this actually solved my current issue

you happen to know why the denied access error might still be there?

When you run Invoke-Command? The likeliest explanation is the the user account to whom the credentials belong is not a member of the local administrators group or the remote management users group on the target machine. If you get it consistently, make sure you specify the realm/domain correctly when passing the username, eg. $username = "AnneMariesDomain\User"

I am currently reading the about remote documentation to hopefully find something around there
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote?view=powershell-7.4

Yes it`s true that the way that the computers are made they do not have access from one to another. There is only one computer with access everywhere. But I am only trying to access for now at leas the local computer using the actual computer name, not LocalHost

@AnneMarie Be sure to check out the Remoting FAQ and the about_Remote_Requirements and about_Remove_Troubleshooting help topics. Best of luck! (and don't forget you're always welcome to ask a new question) :)

@AnneMarie Remoting to localhost on Win 10+ requires local administrator group memberships if I recall correctly, so make sure the credentials are for an account with local admin

ty, I think I will be posting a new question about it soon

I made sure the credentials belong to a local admin and even when I give some random credentials(cause why not trying it) it still fails

@AnneMarie That just means neither works, doesn't tell you anything you didn't know. Check the Security log on your machine (you can use Event Viewer or Get-WinEvent), you'll likely find failed logon event corresponding to the attempts - might tell you why it fails :)

You have a knack for explaining things in a friendly manner.  Thank you.
